# Sending sqlite db over network

Tags: python, sqlite, embedded, binary-data

I have an sqlite database whose data I need to transfer over the network, the server needs to modify the data, and then I need to get the db back and either update my local version or overwrite it with the new db. How should I do this? My coworker at first wanted to scrap the db and just use an .ini file, but this is going to be data that we have to parse pretty frequently (it's a user defined schedule that can change at the user's will, as well as the server's). I said we should just transfer the entire .db as a binary file and let them do with it what they will and then take it back. Or is there a way in sqlite to dump the db to a .sql file like you can do in MySQL so we can transfer it as text?

Any other solutions? This is in python if it makes a difference

update: This is on an embedded platform running linux (I'm not sure what version/kernel or what OS commands we have except the basics that are obvious)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the copy command in your OS.  No reason to overthink this.

Comment: This is on an embedded platform. It's linux (I'm somewhat new to embedded linux), but we have no idea what the server is running.